# Simplify Regex grouping

Tags: c#, regex

```
var pattern = (?:[P|p]rint\("")(.+)(?:""\);?)

var input = Print("Hello World");
```

Results in two groups, the second one captures exactly what I want to capture and the first one is completely useless, how do I remove the first one?

I tried (?:ABC) it didn't work

Comment: You have only 1 capturing group, the other 2 are non capturing groups `(?:` which you can omit. Did you mean `[Pp]rint\("(.+)"\);?` or using a negated char class `[Pp]rint\(("[^"]+)"\);` https://regex101.com/r/YRlPmQ/1

Comment: *how do I remove the first one* - do not use it, just use `match.Groups[1].Value`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pattern uses 1 capturing group `()` and 2 non capturing groups using `(?:)`

Those 2 non capturing groups you can omit as well as the `|` from the character class. I think you also would like to make the `.*` non greedy like `.*?` to prevent overmatching.

Then your pattern could look like(Matching an optional semicolon at the end):

```
[Pp]rint\("(.+?)"\);?
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wXyy7L/1)

You might also use a version with a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) to match not a double quote:

```
[Pp]rint\(("[^"]+)"\);
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YRlPmQ/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
            string input = "var input = Print(\"Hello World\");";
            string pattern = "[Pp]rint\\(\"(?'message'[^\"]+)";

            Match match = Regex.Match(input, pattern);
            string message = match.Groups["message"].Value;
```